# Код, осуществляющий чтение из WordPress базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, база-данных, настройки

Какой php код осуществляет чтение настроек из WordPress базы данных (указанной при установке) и загружает их на страницу `http://digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/` (мой локальный сайт)? (искал в Notepad++ в папке `C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalelectronics.ru`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: за что меня минусуют? Как на странице аккаунта посмотреть причину реакции? (я показал свои поиски)

Comment: Вас минусуют за бессмысленные вопросы. Код, который исполняется на странице, проходит через массу функций ядра WordPress, массу классов плагина Elementor и функции установленной темы. Рассказать всё это в деталях невозможно.

Comment: Лучше бы написали, что именно вы хотите сделать. Скорее всего, вам ни в базу лезть не надо, ни код ядра изучать.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно лезть код

Все содержимое можно подстроить под себя через [хуки-фильтры](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_filter). Обработчики вставлять либо в functions.php, либо в плагин

Например, если нужно изменить содержимое

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_text_to_content' );
function add_text_to_content($content){
    $out = $content . "<p>При копировании статьи, ставьте обратную ссылку, пожалуйста!</p>";
    return $out;
}
```

если изменить заголовок

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_page_title' );
function add_text_to_page_title( $title ) {

        $title = 'Страница: '. $title;

    return $title;
}
```